# Is there a way I could print these IDs in ascending order of their versions?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

[image: This is the multithreaded output]I have an input set that has x number of IDs with their corresponding versions. An id can have multiple versions but they all will be in ascending order in the input set. I use Executor service that takes in certain number of threads, and waits for some time (to simulate I/O delay) and prints the ID and version to console. I want to make sure The console prints all the ID versions in ascending order. I can only modify the add() function and the run method, and add class variables if need be.

I tried using Hashmaps to set the id values to true whenever a thread is working on a dataitem with the specified id. Everytime the run method calls, it checks if the map has that ID value to be true; if so, it is supposed to wait. if not, execute. There is something wrong with the code, so it's mainly an issue with understanding the methods, i think.

The data item class which will be the input. (A set of Dataitems)

```
public class DataItem {
    private int id;
    private int version;
    private long amount;

    public DataItem(int id, int version, long amount) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

The Feedprocessor class that adds threads to the pool

```
public class FeedProcessor extends AbstractFeedProcessor {
    public Map<Integer,Boolean> lock_set = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
    private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public FeedProcessor() {

    }

    public void add(DataItem item) {
            threadPool.submit(new ProcessTask(item));       
        }

}
```

The processtask class that implements runnable

```
class ProcessTask implements Runnable {

        private DataItem item;

        ProcessTask(DataItem item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            saveItem(item);
        }
    }
```

The main function will call the following :

```
static final DataItem[] dataList2 = {
        new DataItem(10000, 1, 100),
        new DataItem(10001, 1, 50),
        new DataItem(10000, 2, 200),
        new DataItem(10001, 2, 51),
        new DataItem(10000, 3, 300),
        new DataItem(10001, 3, 52),
        new DataItem(10000, 4, 400),
        new DataItem(10001, 4, 53)
    };

static void test1() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("====== Test 1 ======");;
        FeedProcessor processor = new FeedProcessor();
        for(DataItem item : dataList1) {
            processor.add(item);
        }
        processor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Test 1 took " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }
```

Currently the results are not in ascending order of their versions, that's the goal.

Comment: `Collections.sort`

Comment: How would that work for threads, since I am using a short variable length delay before its execution to simulate I/O. And i have to be able to use multithreading.

Comment: You wait until you get all the items, then you sort them.

Comment: That just consumes time, and does nothing. The input comes in as a stream, so I want to be able to do it as it comes. The versions in the input will always be in increasing order, so there is no need to sort. It's just a matter of making sure the threads print it in the right order. The output is important, now how we get there.

Comment: If they already come ordered, what is your question then?

Comment: If i did not use multiple threads, I could output the same order as they came in. Now that I'm using a thread pool, with variable delays before printing, the order of the versions is not consistent. I have to make the multithreaded output consistent with the single threaded one.

Comment: Then you have to wait until you have all of them to sort them.

Comment: I added an image to show the result of this code. Is there a way you can do it while the threads are processing? Like have some kind of a lock on the Dataitem ID, so that if a thread has a lock on it, no other thread that is accessing a different 'version' of that same ID will be able to do its work?

Comment: You could sort while the threads are processing, however it is a waste of time because you will have to sort again each time you receive a new item and also you will have to deal with all the concurrency problems of a shared data structure.